# Formally showing $2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^{T-j}x_t x_{t+j} = \sum_{i=1}^{T}x_i( \sum_{j\not=i} x_j)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, proof-writing

Or, if it isn't true please tell me, as I messed up earlier. But I think I may have gotten it correct this time.

Here is what I did; any suggestions (particularly on how I can state things more formally) is much appreciated.

Notice that, for a given $j$, $x_i \in
          \sum_{t=1}^{T-j}x_t x_{t+j}$
                        if $i+j\leq T$. Therefore, each $x_i$ appears in $(T-i)$ terms.
                        Thus, we can write
            $$
    \sum_{j=1}^{T-1}
           \sum_{t=1}^{T-j}x_t x_{t+j}
    = \sum_{i=1}^{T-1} x_i (\sum_{j=i+1}^{T}x_j)
   $$
    But we also have that (using the fact that if $x_j$ must show up in $(j-1)$ terms of the form $x_jx_{i<j}$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,j-1\}$)
        $$
   \sum_{i=1}^{T-1} x_i (\sum_{j=i+1}^{T}x_j) =
    x_T\sum_{i=1}^{T-1} x_i +x_{T-1}\sum_{i=1}^{T-2} + \dots +x_{3}\sum_{i=1}^2x_i + x_1x_2 =  \sum_{i=1}^{T}x_i ( \sum_{j=1}^{i-i}x_j)
  $$
    Putting this together we have that
        $$
  2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^{T-j}x_t x_{t+j} =  
    \sum_{i=1}^{T-1}x_i(\sum_{j=i+1}^T x_j) +
     \sum_{i=1}^T x_i( \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j)
   =  \sum_{i=1}^{T-1}x_i( \sum_{j\not=i} x_j) + x_T\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}x_j
  $$
which can be further simplified to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{T}x_i( \sum_{j\not=i} x_j)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPs approach is correct. Here is a somewhat more formal derivation.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^{T-j}x_tx_{t+j}&=\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}\sum_{t=j+1}^Tx_{t-j}x_t\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j<t\leq T}x_tx_{t-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j<t\leq T}x_tx_j\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{{1\leq t,j\leq T}\atop{t\ne j}}x_tx_j\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\ne t}}^{T}x_tx_j\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index of the inner sum by $j$.
- In (2) we use another representation of (1) to better see the range of summation. We do not change anything.
- In (3) we replace $j \rightarrow t-j$.
- In (4) we use the symmetry when exchanging $i$ with $j$. More explicit
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{1\leq j<t\leq T}x_tx_j=\sum_{1\leq t<j\leq T}x_tx_j=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{{1\leq t,j\leq T}\atop{t\ne j}}x_tx_j
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do not change anything. We just use another representation of (4).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. And I appreciate the comments: I probably would have had some trouble understanding some of the steps if you hadn't included the comments.

Comment: @user106860: You're welcome! Good to see, the answer is helpful. :-)